# How to reduce output file size with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a tool with a very specific use case: I have two JPEG files and I want to create an output video that starts by showing one image for n seconds, crossfades to the other, then shows the second image for n seconds (for showing a before/after). I have this working but my best result so far is a 10 second video with a file size of 842k. I'd like to get as small as possible without losing obvious quality.

I'm an ffmpeg novice and after reading the docs several times, I'm not sure what the best strategy is. Is the fact that the image won't change for the first or second n seconds something that is possible to capitalize on? Are there other more general strategies?

I'm using ffmpeg 3.4.1. Here is my current command-line for testing:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - -vf 'zoompan=d=(4+2)/2:fps=1/2,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100,scale=1280:-2' -c:v libx264 -crf 27 out.mp4
```

Comment: Lowest hanging fruit is to add `-preset veryslow` and/or `-c:v libx265`.

Comment: Thank you! Trying libx265 halved the file size but QuickTime didn't like the file. But the veryslow preset took it to 495k without only a little extra processing time.

Comment: In general for smaller size you'll want decreased resolution, decreased framerate, a different codec (or tweaking the parameters to the existing), or decreasing the "bitrate" (or crf value in your case, which affects bitrate). GL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest suggestions are to:

- Use a slower encoding preset for efficient compression, such as `-preset veryslow`.
- Use a more modern encoder, such as `-c:v libx265`.

Also:

- Add `format=yuv420p` to the end of your filterchain for player compatibility.

Comment: Can you please verify that I'm adding the format correctly? I tried this and QuickTime still complained: ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - -vf 'zoompan=d=(4+2)/2:fps=1/2,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100,scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p' -c:v libx265 -crf 27 -preset veryslow out.mp4

Comment: @DaveBurns Looks good to me. Try adding the `-tag:v hvc1` output option. I am unable to test at the moment.

Comment: Is QuickTime able to play h265 encoded videos? @DaveBurns Try to play it with VLC oder Media Player Classic (MPC) to ensure the video file is valid. If QuickTime is the problem and you can't use another player, you should go back to x264 and play around with CRF value to find a good trade off between quality and file size (trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: Some interesting results: QuickTime can play h265 but requires the tag that @LordNeckbeard suggested. If using h264, using the veryslow preset almost halved the file. Using h265 without veryslow cuts another 40-50k off that. But using veryslow with h265 added the 40-50k back on. Currently my best results are h265 (with the tag) and not using the veryslow preset.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i use this for video mp4 file with 1280x720 duration 01:18:55

*before size 493 MB (517.313.413 bytes)*; --> **after size 197 MB (206.783.999 bytes);**

after, the text inside video is still readable, not blurred. so it will save your space but still visually accepted.

but the process is very slow, you should be patient, or leave it in background while you work

```
ffmpeg -i "webinar.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 30 "webinar-r02.mp4"
```